# System.currentTimeMillis() in android?

Tags: android, date

i face problem with  `System.currentTimeMillis(`) in my project i write some code here where i got problem

```
Date currentDate = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
Log.v("1st",""+currentDate);    
Date currentDate = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()+25*24*60*60*1000);
Log.v("2nd","25th"+currentDate);
```

it displays current date see in first log but i add 25 days to current date it is in 2nd log but it is not working it displays 2 months back day. it is working very fine in between 1*24*60*60*1000 to 24*24*60*60*1000 days.after 24 it is not working please solve my problem

thanks in advance

Comment: Can you add the +24 to your code as 3rd and the paste the print out.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

25*24*60*60*1000>Integer.MAX_VALUE,
your should write as below:

```
new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()+25*24*60*60*1000l);
```

Comment: While this post is not the most elegant solution, java.koma answered exactly what was asked - no reason to vote him down, he brought an interesting bit in his answer.

Answer (score 9):

use [Calendar](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html) instead

```
    Calendar rightNow = Calendar.getInstance()
    rightNow.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 25)
```

and the you can get the date object

Answer (score 4):

You are mixing ints and longs. My java is a little rusty, but try:

```
Date currentDate = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()+25L*24L*60L*60L*1000L);
```

Comment: This is the correct answer, `25*24*60*60*1000` is more what an integer can hold.

Comment: thank u  it is working can i knw  the exact reason y? u r adding L

Comment: Hi. It's because the 25*24*60*60*1000 part of the calculation is performed with int values, but that particular product exceeds the maximum value that can be stored in 32 bits, so arithmetic overflow occurs. Adding L to the end of each number means that it is read as a long value (64 bit) and the calculation result is stored as long. Now we've got enough room to store the result and overflow is avoided.