# How to add time in Android

Tags: android, date, time, simpledateformat, date-format

I have a duration returned from Google Direction API and I convert it to a String like this:

```
Common.DURATION = String.valueOf(hours + " hours " + minutes + " mins " + seconds + " seconds ");
```

What I want is to add up the duration and the current time and display it in a TextView. I have the current time and hours and I convert to a String like this

```
String currentDateTimeString = DateFormat.getTimeInstance().format(new Date());
```

How do I add these together by using the Time method and display it ?

```
                double dist = totalDistance / 1000.0;
                int days = totalSeconds / 86400;
                int hours = (totalSeconds - days * 86400) / 3600;
                int minutes = (totalSeconds - days * 86400 - hours * 3600) / 60;
                int seconds = totalSeconds - days * 86400 - hours * 3600 - minutes * 60;

                Common.DISTANCE = String.valueOf(dist + " km ");
                Common.DURATION = String.valueOf(hours + " hours " + minutes + " mins " + seconds + " seconds ");

                SimpleDateFormat DBFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss", Locale.getDefault());
                String currentDateandTime = DBFormat.format(new Date());

                Date date = null;
                try {
                    date = DBFormat.parse(currentDateandTime);
                } catch (ParseException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                calendar.setTime(date);
                calendar.add(Calendar.HOUR, hours);
                calendar.add(Calendar.MINUTE, minutes);
                calendar.add(Calendar.SECOND, seconds);
                Log.v("1st",""+calendar.getTime());
                Common.ESTIMATED_TIME = String.valueOf(calendar.getTime());
```

Comment: can you provide your current output and also your desired output?

Comment: My current output will display the curren time like 12.21PM + 0 hours + 10 mins like this. while my desired output is 12.31 by adding up the time

Comment: Possible duplicate of [System.currentTimeMillis() in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9785014/system-currenttimemillis-in-android)

Comment: As an aside consider throwing away the long outmoded and notoriously troublesome `DateFormat` and friends, and adding [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your Android project in order to use `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API. It is so much nicer to work with. The `Duration` class of java.time would probably come in handy too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Try this**

pass your duration in below three parameters.

```
int additionalHour = 0;
int additionalMinute = 0;
int additionalSeconds = 0;


SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy:MM:dd:HH:mm", Locale.getDefault());
String currentDateandTime = sdf.format(new Date());

Date date = null;
try {
    date = sdf.parse(currentDateandTime);
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTime(date);
calendar.add(Calendar.HOUR, additionalHour);
calendar.add(Calendar.MINUTE, additionalMinute);
calendar.add(Calendar.SECOND, additionalSeconds);

System.out.println("Desired Time here "+calendar.getTime());
```

**Formate Date**

```
private static SimpleDateFormat DBFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss", Locale.getDefault());

public String getFormatDate() {
        Date date = new Date();
        return DBFormat.format(date);
    }
```

Comment: I have a question. What i get is like this : "Thu Jan 01 19:25:15 GMT+08:00 1970" , i need only get the time such as "19:25:15" or "7:25:15 PM/AM" , what to do to get the hour/minute/second? I tried to change the SimpleDateFormat to (""h:mm a") yet still cannot.I refer https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat

Comment: I still cannot get the time like this : "19.25:15", i will update my code for you sir,

Comment: its okay bro. I solved it. My mistakes, i apologies